# PHP session not working in iOS captive portal

Tags: php, ios

I'm developing a UniFi wifi login portal that is working with Windows, OSX, and Android, but fails with iOS. All session data is NULL in iOS.

Here's the index page:

```
<?php

// PHP SCRIPT FOR SIMPLE PORTAL

session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id']; // User's MAC address
$_SESSION['ap'] = $_GET['ap']; // AP mac
$_SESSION['ssid'] = $_GET['ssid']; // SSID the user is on
$_SESSION['time'] = $_GET['t']; // Time the user attempted a request of the portal

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>WI-FI Login</title>
</head>
<body class="login-page">
    <div class="login-content content-box">
        <form name="login" action="authorized.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-controls">
                <!-- submit (only for no authentication) -->
                <section id="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" name="connect" value="LOGIN" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="3" />
                       <br style="clear:both;">
                </section>  
            </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is authorized.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

function sendAuthorization($id, $minutes)
{
$unifiServer = 'https://localhost:8443';
$unifiUser = 'username';
$unifiPass = 'password';

// Start Curl for login
$ch = curl_init();
// We are posting data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// Set up cookies
$cookie_file = '/tmp/unifi_cookie';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
// Allow Self Signed Certs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
// Force SSL3 only
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
// Login to the UniFi controller
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$unifiServer/api/login");
$data = json_encode(array("username" => $unifiUser, "password" => $unifiPass));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
// send login command
curl_exec ($ch);

// Send user to authorize and the time allowed
$data = json_encode(array(
'cmd'=>'authorize-guest',
'mac'=>$id,
'minutes'=>$minutes));

// Send the command to the API
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer . '/api/s/default/cmd/stamgr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_exec ($ch);

// Logout of the UniFi Controller
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/logout');
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);
}

if ($_POST) // Check to see if the form has been posted to
{
ob_start();
echo sendAuthorization($_SESSION['id'], (12*60));
ob_end_clean();
}

?>

<p>Authorized!</p>

<p><?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?></p> <!-- NULL on iOS -->
```

Any suggestions? I'm running a Windows server with IIS -- could that be an issue?

**UPDATE:**

Appears to be a session issue. `session_start` always returns TRUE but the `session_id` changes on iOS devices. Why is this only happening on iOS?

Comment: basic debugging: check the return value from `session_start()`, and check `session_id()`. if you get a boolean false or the ID's changing, then you've got session issues.

Comment: Thanks for looking. `session_start` is OK, but `session_id` keeps changing on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a session cookie with the following appears to have resolved the problem:

```
// Set a session cookie:
$lifetimecookie = 180; // 3 minutes
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time()+$lifetimecookie);
```